# Copy setup of GA and GTM from one account to another without copying data

Tags: google-analytics, copy, migration, google-tag-manager

How can I copy setup of GA and GTM from one account to another without copying data?

According to [the](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6370521?hl=en) documentation it is not possible:

> All reporting data associated with a property is moved (not copied) to the destination account.

But maybe someone knows some kind of a trick?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked is about property moving, which is basically Google's term for moving GA data from one account to another. So in that case moving the data is the whole point. It is true however that you cannot easily copy a GA configuration - the closest would be to set up properties and views programmatically via the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/), but that is a lot of work (too much if you only want to do this once) and still does not cover all the settings.

You can easily move a GTM installation from one GTM account to another. Just [export the container in the admin section and import it in the admin section of the new account](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106997). This will not copy any data.

Comment: Thank you. So, the main point is to do the GA setup replication manually if it is needed only once. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. Even copying a view within the same property will not copy all view settings, and copying a property to another account without the data does not work.

Comment: Also to emphasize the point, property moving (as in your documentation link) does not copy the property, it moves it to a different account (which means it's no longer in the previous account, but it still retains its unique tracking id). Else you could just copy the property and nuke the views (as new views start empty).